# Travis-CI will not build a new GitHub Repo

Tags: github, travis-ci, python-sphinx

I created a new repo on github and added the .travis.yml file and some sphinx documents but travis won't trigger a build. I can push to another older repository and https://travis-ci.org builds fine. I double checked that the .travis.yml file is exactly like other repositories that do build. I checked github Authorizing OAuth Apps and travis is there.

.travis.yml

```
    language: python

install:
- pip install sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme mock

script:
- sphinx-build -Wv docs/source docs/html

deploy:
# publish docs on push
- provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  keep-history: false
  github_token: $GH_TOKEN
  local_dir: docs/html
  on:
    branch: master
```

I made a [second repo](https://github.com/jethornton/build-test) just to make sure I did it correctly.

I follow [my instructions](https://jethornton.github.io/sphinx-travis/) for setting up a GitHub, sphinx and travis each time I create a repo.

Comment: Do you pay for Travis or have free credits remaining?

Comment: I use travis-ci.org which is free.

Comment: Which is shutting down, so I'd be surprised if they were onboarding new projects.

Comment: Ok, that could be the issue. I guess it's time to move on...